# Populating attribute table with attributes from table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to populate an attribute table of a feature with attributes from another feature. I have been able to segregate the input data into fields named "From", "Eastings" and "Northings". I find this is not such a difficult task to carry out as this code helped. The problem now is the input data has only four(4) rows but when I run my script, it multiplies the number of rows and I end up with twenty rows. I am quite sure I need to change something in the code, i am not sure where as I am relatively new to python.

here is my code:

```
pr.addAttributes([QgsField('FROM',  QVariant.String)])
vpr.addAttributes([QgsField('Eastings',  QVariant.Double)])
vpr.addAttributes([QgsField('Northings',QVariant.Double)])
vlayer.updateFields()

vlayer.startEditing()
for things in vlayer.getFeatures():
    for i in new_attribs:
        things['FROM'] = i[0] 
        things['Eastings'] = i[1]
        things['Northings']=i[2]
        things.setAttributes(i[0])
        vpr.addFeatures([things])
           
        vlayer.updateFeature(things)

    vlayer.commitChanges()
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

How do I get only the four(4) rows I need?

Comment: What is `new_attribs`

Comment: new_attribs is the attributes i need to populate the layer with.

Comment: `vlayer` already as 4 features at the begining but no attributes ?
Is `new_attribs` a list of lists ? Like this : `new_attribs = [["SGC A562 16 1", 1099307.4, 307285.64], ["SGC A562 16 2", 1099349.96, 307243.6], ["SGC A562 16 3", 1099249.74, 307139.4], ["SGC A562 16 4", 1099203.19, 307170.55]]`

if `vlayer` already as features I don't understand why you add more with `vpr.addFeatures([things])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least to change the code to the following. The main change has been desindenting `vpr.addFeatures([things])` to avoid adding unwanted "garbage" features. I'm also surprised why you edit the `vlayer` if you want to add your feature to `vpr`?

```py
pr.addAttributes([QgsField('FROM',  QVariant.String)])
vpr.addAttributes([QgsField('Eastings',  QVariant.Double)])
vpr.addAttributes([QgsField('Northings',QVariant.Double)])
vlayer.updateFields()

vlayer.startEditing()
for things in vlayer.getFeatures():
    for i in new_attribs:
        things['FROM'] = i[0] 
        things['Eastings'] = i[1]
        things['Northings'] = i[2]
        things.setAttributes(i[0])
    vpr.addFeatures([things])
    vlayer.updateFeature(things)

    vlayer.commitChanges()
```